# Execute powershell string via CMD

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, certificate

I try to execute the following command in console:

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -Command `"Get-ChildItem "Cert:\CurrentUser\My" | WHERE{$_.Extensions['Certificate Template Name'] -match 'CA'}`"
```

But I get this error:
[image: error pic here]

I need to execute this command in CMD, not ps1 script.

Comment: Please don't add the error message as image. Add it as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was in issue with your double quotes.

I've changed it slightly:

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo -Command "Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My | where {$_.Extensions['Certificate Template Name'] -match 'CA'}"
```

Comment: Wow, thanx buddy!
Sorry for idiot mistake. First im take path on quotes, then try to shield them. My bad (:

Comment: You only need the quote the path if it contains whitespaces.